# select specific columns from jpa left outer join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to build a query using JPA 2.0 Criteria API, based on the two entities:

```
person(id, name)
address(person_id, house_no, street, city, country)
```

The corresponding entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "house_no")
    private String houseNumber;

    private String street;

    private String city;

    private String country;
}
```

Now, I want to fetch all the persons, and I have a query like:

```
 List<Person> getAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Person> all = cq.select(root);
    TypedQuery<Person> tq = manager.createQuery(all);
    List<Person> res = tq.getResultList();
    return res;
}
```

While, this query works, and gives me all the persons with the address member. I just want the city and country fields, i_e I don't want to fetch house_no and street.

SQl Query would be:

```
select p.*, a.city, a.country from person as p left join address as a on p.id=a.person_id;
```

JPQL for the said query might be something like:

```
SELECT p, p.address.city, p.address.country FROM person p LEFT JOIN p.address address
```

But this doesn't seem to work!! Person entity holds the Address and cannot hold the city and country attributes.
how do I put the correct JPQL, and the corresponding JPA 2.0 criteria query? Or do I have to change my entity structure?

Comment: Since you already join `p.address` under the alias `address` in your JPQL you should use that in the select, i.e. instead of `p.address.city` you'd just do `address.city`.

Comment: Okay, but even after changing that I cannot use the Person entity to hold the results. Right?

Comment: The results of such a query would be of type _Object[]_. Are you thinking you can do this just to retrieve a Person with specific fields? because that is not what a result is for.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted Person with specific address fields. Is there any way I can do that with hibernate?

Comment: What should that `Person` class look like? What would be the difference in just loading the person and the address in one run? If the address just contains those few fields you'd probably not gain much from just loading 40% of the fields (which I'd assume would constitute more than 50% of the memory). If you _really_ want to load a specific object then either use the constructor syntax in HQL (don't know whether criteria support that as well) or just iterate over the `List<Object[]>` you get and create those objects yourself.